# After clicking on an internal link in a PDF in the native Chrome PDF viewer, how can I go back to the location of the text where the link is located?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, pdf, links, navigation

After clicking on an internal link in a PDF in the native Chrome PDF viewer, how can I go back to the location of the text where the link is located?

Example of internal link  in a [PDF](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2008.03274.pdf) (green rectangles  as viewed in Acrobat):

[image: link]

I use Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Comment: Can't test, don't have Chrome, but have you tried ⌘  [ same as 'back a page'

Comment: @Tetsujin Ctrl + [ rotates the page. Alt  + [ does nothing.

Comment: Ctrl ? I'd assumed Mac, no clue on Windows, but you ought to include your platform in your question.

Comment: @Tetsujin I sometimes use Ubuntu and OS OX as well, so I'm interested in all three OSes. But I don't have OS X with me right now. Shortcuts typically don't change that much on Chrome between OSes.

Comment: Well, on Mac it's usually Cmd [ though tbh, Google tends to ignore the Mac Toolbox for most things (which is why I generally avoid anything they make)

Comment: @Tetsujin ⌘ [ on OS X doesn't work: it goes to the previous webpage.

Answer (score 0):

You can view pdf with some chrome extensions, like

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pdf-viewer/oemmndcbldboiebfnladdacbdfmadadm?hl=zh-CN

and use ⌘ plus left-arrow.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).